# I can't get this example from DirectWrite to run in V2015

Tags: c++, windows, directwrite

I got the example below from this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371554(v=vs.85).aspx) in MS, but the code doesn't link due to this message:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DWriteCreateFactory@12 referenced in function _wmain

I repeat the code below to facilitate its reading:

```
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <new>

// SafeRelease inline function.
template <class T> inline void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

void wmain()
{
    IDWriteFactory* pDWriteFactory = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = DWriteCreateFactory(
            DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
            __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
            reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pDWriteFactory)
            );

    IDWriteFontCollection* pFontCollection = NULL;

    // Get the system font collection.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pDWriteFactory->GetSystemFontCollection(&pFontCollection);
    }

    UINT32 familyCount = 0;

    // Get the number of font families in the collection.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        familyCount = pFontCollection->GetFontFamilyCount();
    }

    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < familyCount; ++i)
    {
        IDWriteFontFamily* pFontFamily = NULL;

        // Get the font family.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFontCollection->GetFontFamily(i, &pFontFamily);
        }

        IDWriteLocalizedStrings* pFamilyNames = NULL;

        // Get a list of localized strings for the family name.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFontFamily->GetFamilyNames(&pFamilyNames);
        }

        UINT32 index = 0;
        BOOL exists = false;

        wchar_t localeName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Get the default locale for this user.
            int defaultLocaleSuccess = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(localeName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);

            // If the default locale is returned, find that locale name, otherwise use "en-us".
            if (defaultLocaleSuccess)
            {
                hr = pFamilyNames->FindLocaleName(localeName, &index, &exists);
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && !exists) // if the above find did not find a match, retry with US English
            {
                hr = pFamilyNames->FindLocaleName(L"en-us", &index, &exists);
            }
        }

        // If the specified locale doesn't exist, select the first on the list.
        if (!exists)
            index = 0;

        UINT32 length = 0;

        // Get the string length.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFamilyNames->GetStringLength(index, &length);
        }

        // Allocate a string big enough to hold the name.
        wchar_t* name = new (std::nothrow) wchar_t[length+1];
        if (name == NULL)
        {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }

        // Get the family name.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFamilyNames->GetString(index, name, length+1);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Print out the family name.
            wprintf(L"%s\n", name);
        }

        SafeRelease(&pFontFamily);
        SafeRelease(&pFamilyNames);

        delete [] name;
    }

    SafeRelease(&pFontCollection);
    SafeRelease(&pDWriteFactory);
}
```

As these are my first steps in DirectWrite, I'm clueless about the error message mentioned above.

Comment: did you link in `Dwrite.lib` ?

Comment: @PeterT  Thanks. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN page on DWriteCreateFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that you must include `dwrite.h` (assuming you have done since code compiled) and link `dwrite.lib`.

You must explicitely add that library to your VisualStudio project.

Comment: Could you tell me how to link to `dwrite.lib` in my project?

Comment: I've just added `dwrite.lib` into Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old forum, but thought I'd add that you can also link the lib by using #pragma comment(lib, "dwrite.lib")